# Fit Surface Plasmon Resonance (SPR) data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to fit association-dissociation SPR kinetics data for a protein and small molecule for two concentrations using `ggplot2`. The data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-A4NwQOsIqfsIyJkyYk587ffwpA1cBkC/view?usp=sharing).
The `time` variable indicates the time in seconds, the `sample` variable indicates the two concentrations (32nM and 8nM), and the `values` variable is the readout.

I have imported the `data` and running the following code to plot:

```
# LINE PLOT
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = time, y = values), size = 1, color = "black") +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = time, y = values, color = sample), method = "loess", se = F) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA)) + 
  #scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 60)) +
  scale_color_npg(breaks = c("2nM", "4nM", "8nM", "16nM", "32nM")) +
  theme_linedraw() +
  labs(x = "Time (seconds)",
       y = "Response Units") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Here is the plot:
[image]

As you can see that the fit did not work using `method = "loess"`. I need something like this(there are 5 concentrations here):
[image]

The fitting requires 1:1 Langmuir model but I am not sure how I can do that in `ggplot`. Can someone please help me?

Here is the equation:
[image]

This is from the [pbm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbm/vignettes/vignette.html) package that fits this kind of plots.

Comment: You need to find a package that does what you want and then determine if it has a ggplot wrapper. You clearly have data that has two separate time periods: 0-120 and 120 forward. Ggplot itself does not have fitting algorithms.

Comment: I know nothing about Surface Plasmon Resonance but you are asking us to write a non-linear fitting function in a very specific field. See if package [pbm](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=pbm) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data are smooth enough that you need only use `geom_line`, not `geom_smooth`:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, values, color = sample)) +
  geom_line(size = 2, na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(color = 'black', size = 1) +
  theme_linedraw(base_size = 16) +
  xlim(c(0, 400))
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

It is possible to fit the results to the data using non-linear least squares, employing the `binding1to1` function from `pbm`, but it requires a bit of method tweaking to get the model to fit. It would probably be better to create a model then plot the predictions rather than using `geom_smooth`. However, if you really wanted to, you could do:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, values, color = sample)) +
  geom_smooth(method = nls, se = FALSE, n = 1000,
              formula = y ~ binding1to1(x, 123, 32e-9, kon, koff, rmax),
              method.args = list(
                start = list(kon = 2000, koff = 0.02, rmax = 2e4),
                control = nls.control(minFactor = 1e-6, maxiter = 1000)
              ),
   data =  df[df$time > 0 & df$sample == "32nM",]) +
  geom_smooth(method = nls, se = FALSE, n = 1000,
              formula = y ~ binding1to1(x, 123, 8e-9, kon, koff, rmax),
              method.args = list(
                start = list(kon = 3000, koff = 0.02, rmax = 2e4),
                control = nls.control(minFactor = 1e-9, maxiter = 10000)
              ),
              data =  df[df$time > 0 & df$sample == "8nM",]) +
  geom_point(color = 'black', size = 1) +
  theme_linedraw(base_size = 16) +
  xlim(c(0, 400))
```

[image]

If you want to actually fit a model from which to extract the parameters *and* plot, you can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(pbm)

df <- read.csv("SPR.csv") %>%
  filter(time >= 0) %>%
  mutate(sample = as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", sample)) * 1e-9,
         values = values * 1e-3) %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  mutate(tmax = time[which.max(values)])

fit_fun <- function(time, tmax, sample, kon, koff, rmax) {
  unlist(Map(function(time, tmax, sample) {
    binding1to1(time, tmax, sample, kon, koff, rmax)
    }, time, tmax, sample))
}

mod <- nls(values ~ fit_fun(time, tmax, sample, kon, koff, rmax),
    data = df,
    start = list(kon = 3000, koff = 0.02, rmax = 2),
    control = nls.control(minFactor = 1e-9, maxiter = 10000))
```

This gives us a model with the best fitting values for the various parameters:

```r
mod
#> Nonlinear regression model
#>   model: values ~ fit_fun(time, tmax, sample, kon, koff, rmax)
#>    data: df
#>       kon      koff      rmax 
#> 8.925e+05 2.521e-03 5.445e-02 
#>  residual sum-of-squares: 5.219e-05
#> 
#> Number of iterations to convergence: 536 
#> Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.155e-07
```

We can then predict the output of the model over the range of our input variables:

```
pred_df <- expand.grid(time = 0:400, sample = c(8, 32) * 1e-9, 
                       tmax = df$tmax[1])

pred_df$values <- predict(mod, pred_df)
```

And we can plot it like this:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, values, color = factor(sample))) +
  geom_line(data = pred_df, size = 1) +
  geom_point(color = 'black', size = 1) +
  theme_linedraw(base_size = 16) +
  xlim(c(0, 400))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to use `geom_smooth` with a fitting equation instead of `geom_line`.

Comment: @Shubham Do you know the general form of the equation you wish to fit?

Comment: I have edited the post above with the equation.

Comment: @Shubham I have edited my answer to include the best fit from the `binding1to1` model. It doesn't look perfect, but this is the optimum fit of this model to your data.